# bash scripting yesterdays zip file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash

yesterday= date --date="1 day ago" +%Y%m%d | tr -d '\n'
remote_file="76.99.20.129\$yesterday.zip"

echo $remote_file
```

output:

```
2012010476.99.20.129$yesterday.zip
```

What is going on here?

I want to pass this variable to a wget call and automatically download a file

Comment: i Have tried remote_file="76.99.20.129\/$yesterday.zip"

Comment: Is this a copy-and-paste of your code or is this re-typed? It feels like there's enough wrong with it that I suspect it is re-typed. Please don't re-type -- I don't like putting effort into debugging code that never actually existed. Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact output you want to get, so we know what the goal is?

Answer (score 3):

Two problems here. The first is that you're actually not capturing the output of the date command in the variable:

```
pax> yesterday= date --date="1 day ago" +%Y%m%d | tr -d '\n'
20120105pax@pax-desktop:~$ echo $yesterday
<<no output>>
```

What that command of yours is doing is setting `yesterday` to an empty string for the duration of running the `date` command, a nifty `bash` feature I call the one-shot environment setting but which `bash` almost certainly calls something else. It's no different to:

```
xyzzy=plugh dosomething
```

in which the `dosomething` command has an entry for `xyzzy` in its environment but, on return, the shell that started it doesn't. Note that this is different from:

```
export xyzzy=plugh
dosomething
# Here xyzzy is still set.
```

The second is that you're escaping the `$`, meaning the variable won't be touched.

Try:

```
pax> yesterday=$(date --date="1 day ago" +%Y%m%d)
pax> remote_file="76.99.20.129_${yesterday}.zip"
pax> echo ${remote_file}
76.99.20.129_20120105.zip
```

I put the underscore in just so you could see the delineation clearly. Remove it to get the behaviour (I think) you originally intended.

If the string you're actually after should have the backslash in it, you'll need to escape that so it doesn't affect the `$`:

```
pax> yesterday=$(date --date="1 day ago" +%Y%m%d)
pax> remote_file="76.99.20.129\\${yesterday}.zip"
pax> echo ${remote_file}
76.99.20.129\20120105.zip
```

Note the *double* `\` above to achieve the escaping.

You'll also note that I've surrounded environment variable names with `{}`. This is good practice to avoid problems where you want to add (for example) the letter `d` to the contents of the environment variable `abc`.

The command `echo $abcd` will give you the contents of the `abcd` environment variable whereas what you need is `echo ${abc}d`. I always prefer this explicit notation.

In addition, thanks to holygeek, the `tr -d '\n'` is not really necessary in this case, so I've removed it as well.

Comment: You can drop the ``| tr -d '\n'`` as it is not really necessary as the shell does it for you automatically in command substitution.

Answer (score 1):

use `${}` to escape:

```
remote_file="76.99.20.129\\${yesterday}.zip"
```